# Error creating channel but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have an error on creating an channel:

```
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

The orderer says the following

```
WARN 025 [channel: testchannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.0.121:39954 because of error: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

I use this commands inside the peer container:

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto-config/peer/msp/users/admin/msp/

peer channel create -c testchannel -f testchannel.tx --outputBlock testchannel.block --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/crypto-config/peer/tls-msp/cacerts/192-168-0-114-7054.pem -o 192.168.0.124:7050
```

My policies for the channel are the following:

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is 
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
```

I am using etcdraft with 3 nodes and v 1.4.1

EDIT 1:

I dont have a Cli container, should I do it from that cli container?
Right now I am executing all this commands from the peer container.

EDIT 2:

If I add the admincerts folder with the certificate of the admin on the msp folder of the admin:

- admin

  - msp

    - admincerts
    - signcerts
    - ...

I get the error:

this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

But If I don't add it I get the error:

this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it, so, this was a problem with the policies. I had to edit on the confitx.yml the policies on the organization level.

I added any member as reader and writer and only admins as admins

```
    - &Example
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Example

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: ExampleMSP

        MSPDir: <pathtomsp>

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ExampleMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ExampleMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ExampleMSP.admin')"
```

Comment: I'm still facing the above issue even after your mentioned changes, can you please share your modified configtx.yaml file? Thank you in advance